# Why can't SortedSet be used as a Priority Queue or Min-Heap?

Tags: c#

I was attempting to solve the running median problem (on [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-find-the-running-median)) using a sorted set. Only it's elements don't appear properly sorted.

See it in action here: http://rextester.com/NGBN25779

```
public class RunningMedian{

    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    SortedSet<int> sorted = new SortedSet<int>();

    public void Add(int num){
        list.Add(num);
        sorted.Add(num);
    }
    public double MedianNotWorking(){
        return GetMedian(sorted.ToArray());
    }
    public double MedianWorking(){
        int[] arr = list.ToArray();
        Array.Sort(arr);
        return GetMedian(arr);
    }
    public double GetMedian(int[] arr){
        int idx = list.Count / 2;
        if(arr.Length % 2 == 0){
            return (double)((double)(arr[idx] + arr[idx-1]) / 2);
        }else{
            return arr[idx];
        }
    }

}

static void Main(String[] args) {
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] a = new int[n];

    RunningMedian heap = new RunningMedian();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        heap.Add(a[i]);

        //double median = heap.GetMedian();
        double median = heap.MedianNotWorking();
        Console.WriteLine(median.ToString("F1"));
    }
}
```

For the most part the sorted set does work. However at larger input sizes it begins to give wrong answers. It may not be the optimal solution to the problem but I'm curious as to why it fails at all. C# doesn't have a min-heap / priority queue so why can't sorted sets be used as a substitute?

*Edited to include full code from hackerrank.

Here is an input file.
Input
http://textuploader.com/dovni

Expected
http://textuploader.com/dovnb

Output
http://textuploader.com/dovwj

Conflicts appear near the end

Expected
(Skipping 1-364)
54240.0
54576.5
54913.0
54576.5
54240.0

Results
(Skipping 1-364)
54240.0
54576.5
54913.0
54963.0
54576.5

Comment: For which input values example does your code fail? Please edit your question to include the code which uses your `RunningMedian` class so we can see (and try) why it fails.

Comment: Updated to include full code, input, output, and expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SortedSet` collections contain by definition only unique values. However your input file contains the number `21794` twice, which means that the second `21794` entry doesn't get added to your `SortedSet`. So your sorted set will contain fewer values than your list and your whole algorithm doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this could be achieved by definition of new IComparator behavior for the SortedSet comparison. For the min priority queue it would be smth like this:

```
public class PriorityQueue<K,V> where K : IComparable
                                where V : IComparable
{
    private SortedSet<Node<K,V>> _set;
    private readonly int _amount;

    public PriorityQueue(int amount)
    {
        _set = new SortedSet<Node<K,V>>(new PriorityComparer<K,V>());
        _amount = amount;
    }

    public void Add(Node<K,V> value)
    {
        if (_amount > _set.Count)
            _set.Add(value);
        else
        {
            if (_set.Max.Val.CompareTo(value.Val) == 1)
            {
                _set.Remove(_set.Max);
                _set.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public Node<K,V> ExtractMax()
    {
        var max = _set.Max;
        _set.Remove(max);

        return max;
    }

    public Node<K,V> ExtractMin()
    {
        var min = _set.Min;
        _set.Remove(min);

        return min;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty => _set.Count == 0;
}

public struct Node<K,V> where K : IComparable
                        where V : IComparable
{
    public K Key;
    public V Val;

    public Node(K key, V val)
    {
        Val = val;
        Key = key;
    }
}

public class PriorityComparer<K,V> : IComparer<Node<K,V>> where K: IComparable
                                                          where V: IComparable
{
    public int Compare(Node<K,V> i, Node<K,V> y)
    {
        var compareresult = i.Val.CompareTo(y.Val);

        if (compareresult == 0)
            return i.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);

        return compareresult;
    }
}
```